# how can i use __construct in conjuction with controller in laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, construct

I have built laravel applications in Laravel 4 and Laravel 5, but I decided this time to write all my tests first, having never previously written tests at all for trivial apps.

Here is my Account class - for illustration

```
class Account extends Model
{
    protected $customer_id;
    protected $bookmaker_id;
    protected $balance;
    protected $profit;

    public function __construct($customer_id, $bookmaker_id, $balance, $profit) {
        $this->customer_id = $customer_id;
        $this->bookmaker_id = $bookmaker_id;
        $this->balance = $balance;
        $this->profit = $profit;
      }
}
```

So all my unit tests run fine:

My route is set up correctly to the page I want to display

```
Route::get('/accounts', 'AccountController@index');
```

but this is where it goes wrong. Actually trying to run a page to get a list of accounts is troublesome. I know there is more to do with the controller class but here is what I have.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Account;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $accounts = Account::all();
        return view('account.index', compact('accounts'));
    }
}
```

Then I get this error -

```
ErrorException in Account.php line 14:
Missing argument 1 for App\Account::__construct(), called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mb-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 665 and defined
```

Can someone tell me how I should be setting up my controller please? Until I added the __construct() for my unit tests this was all going ok.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By using __construct, it expects arguments any time you initialize it. So instead, you'd use

```
$accountModel = new Account($customer_id, $bookmaker_id, $balance, $profit);
$accounts = $accountModel->all();
```

If you want to use those variables for creating a new model, look into [$fillable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Comment: thanks for getting back... not sure i follow though. What I'm trying to do is retrieve a list of all accounts... wouldn't $accountModel just be a new Account instance?

Comment: Hmm, you're correct. What are you trying to accomplish with the __construct?

Comment: the __construct was set up to accommodate a setup() method in phpUnit for unit testing. i'm not particularly attached to it only that i thought i needed it for my tests to refactor them down into something more managable.

Comment: ok so it looks like i'm overwriting the core __construct method. i didn't want to; it's an unwelcome side effect of following a tutorial when i don't know much around the subject! i've got some help at laracasts forum so i'll post back here with progress